# Add a [hls] tag - people keep auto-completing to [hlsl]!

Tags: feature-request, synonym-request

Can we add [hls](/questions/tagged/hls) tag as synonym for [http-live-streaming](/questions/tagged/http-live-streaming)?

I keep finding questions being tagged with [hlsl](/questions/tagged/hlsl) (high level shader language). Presumably because people are typing "hls" and blindly auto-completing.

Will a tag synonym fix this issue?

Here are a few examples of me having to fix this: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15241098/165500) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16043343/165500) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16120124/165500) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17227504/165500).

Comment: A tag synonym will fix the issue, but I don't know if it's possible since the tag [tag:hls] doesn't exists.

Comment: Why not get rid of hlsl completely and rename it to high-level-shader-language? Make things clearer rather...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Maybe people use most `HLSL` instead of `high-level-shader-language`. What if future people try to write `HLSL` and doesn't find any matches? This solution will involve an other synonym I guess..

Comment: @j0k I don't understand why that's a problem. Shouldn't it be fairly trivial to create the tag?

Comment: Is there any way to bump this request? Just cleaned up yet another one of these [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16043343/165500).

Comment: @AndrewRussell consider this request bumped.